# Subtract Amount Row By Row in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me with SQL database query by decreasing amount row by row.

I have table with 3 columns id, amount and result. And have 4 rows as Shown:

```
id  amount  result    
1   3000    
2   1000    
3   500    
4   1000
```

And the Desired Result is:

```
id   amount  result
1   3000     0
2   1000     2000
3   500      1500
4   1000    500
```

I want to decrease amount in result row by row. So how can I update decrease amount to result.

Thank you all

Comment: Shouldn't the first row be 3000?

Comment: which dbms you are using (mssql, mysql, oracle, postgre)?

Comment: Search for `LEAD` or `LAG` (analytic function - Oracle, window function - MSSQL). It will help you subtract row by row and get ABS.

Comment: I am using MS SQL database. Yeah I will search for LEAD or LAB. thank you.

Comment: But Its not OK with LEAD or LAG. sorry.

Comment: Post your desired outcome in a more visual way (with tablular/text table format).

Comment: Sure, this can also be done without using LEAD/LAG, even though the code will not be as pretty, I added a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, with just old fashioned plain SQL.
Table: tbl
columns: id, val, sum

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(id INT, val INT, sum INT)
INSERT INTO tbl SELECT 1, 3000, 0
INSERT INTO tbl SELECT 2, 1000, 0
INSERT INTO tbl SELECT 3, 500, 0
INSERT INTO tbl SELECT 4, 1000, 0
SELECT * FROM tbl

SELECT t1.id, t1.val, t0.val-ISNULL(t2.s, t1.val) AS s
FROM tbl AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    -- Calculate the value to subtract (all rows with same or lower Id, except first)
    SELECT t1.id, SUM(t2.val) AS s
    FROM tbl AS t1
    INNER JOIN tbl AS t2
     ON t2.id <= t1.id 
     AND t2.id > 1
    GROUP BY t1.id
) AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
INNER JOIN tbl AS t0 ON t0.id=1 -- Join in the first row, to subtract from (could also be MIN(id) or whatever you need)
```

To do the update, if you're happy with the results, replace the SELECT-row with:

```
UPDATE t1 SET sum = t0.val-ISNULL(t2.s, t1.val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a windowed `SUM()` with first determining which amount sums and which rests.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Amount INT)

INSERT INTO @Data (Amount)
VALUES
    (3000),
    (1000),
    (500),
    (1000)

;WITH Data AS 
(
    SELECT
        D.ID,
        D.Amount,
        SignedAmount = CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Data AS N WHERE D.ID - 1 = N.ID) THEN D.Amount ELSE -1 * D.Amount END
    FROM
        @Data AS D
)
SELECT
    D.ID,
    D.Amount,
    Result = SUM(D.SignedAmount) OVER (ORDER BY D.ID ASC)
FROM
    Data AS D
```

In this example we assign a positive amount to the first record and a negative amount to the rest, then just do a running sum.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
;with cte
AS
(
 SELECT id,Amount,0 AS Result, Amount AS Result1 from tab1 where id=1
 Union ALL
 SELECT t1.id,t1.Amount,(t2.Result1-t1.Amount) AS Result,(t2.Result1-t1.Amount) AS Result1 
FROM tab1 t1
JOIN cte t2 on t1.id=t2.id+1  
) 

SELECT id,Amount,Result from cte
```

SQL Fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/35bbe/9